# Image Processing Issue: Fill NaNs in image, which mostly consists of NaNs

Tags: matlab, image-processing, interpolation, nan

I have a dataset / image `DD` like the one in this image:

[image]

(by the way: is there a way of uploading small data sets here, so that you can actually work with the same data I use, without having to put them in the code?)

Colored pixels in the image represent height/depth ranging from 0 to about 400  meters. Blue pixels are `NaN`.

Now what I need to do is to interpolate the pixel values WITHIN the displayed object, but without interpolating the whole image.

I tried using the function `inpaint_nans` from the file-exchange, which has helped me quite often and again, it did a decent job:

[image]

```
imagesc(inpaint_nans(DD,4))
```

However, the runtime is fairly long for large images of ~3000x3000 pixels (and I have a few of them!) and it is not exactly, what I am looking for. Is there a function within the image processing toolbox maybe, that restricts the interpolation to the existing boundaries of my object without taking into account the surrounding NaNs?

I also used `interp2` like so:

```
[xi,yi] = meshgrid(1:size(DD,2),1:size(DD,1));
zi = interp2(xi,yi,DD,xi,yi,'method');
imagesc(zi)
```

where I tried `linear`, `nearest` and `cubic`for `method`. Non of them did the job. `nearest`did not do anything, while the rest removed more and more "good" pixels and substituted them by `NaN`s. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

EDIT: PROCESSING:

I ran a simulation in a different program, that was based on triangular meshs. For each node of the mesh (X,Y), the water depth is written to an ascii file. In the center of the stream, the 2 triangles fit in one pixel (90x90meters), e.g., I get water depth values for the corners of a pixel, not the pixel itself. At surrounding, the simulation works with a larger spacing (as is evident from the regular NaN values within the floodplain). Here, 2 triangles make up a rectangle of 180x180 meters (4 pixels). Because I only get values for the nodes of the triangles again, the calculated water depth value is assigned to every second, not every pixel. 
Now I thought, the easiest method would be to interpolate between the pixels. Another valid (maybe better) solution, would be to assign the node value (depth) to the surrounding 2 / 4 pixels:
[image: no description]

Comment: If it's not too big, you can just post your data here as a code block. Otherwise, use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or similar.

Comment: Are the blue pixels between the colored "blocks" in your original also `NaN`?

Comment: @Rody Thank you for the advice! I will check out pastebin. 90x100 pixel might be a bit to large for just pasting them here.

And YES, the blue pixels within the colored objects are NaNs as well. In fact, these are the ones I need to fill! I do not care about the ones outside of the object (=river), but the once within are crucial. They are the result from transorming triangular data back to raster data!

Comment: hmmmmmmmm...that last sentence sets off a few alarm bells over here...So, if I understood you correctly, you get data in some triangulation, convert that data to an equally-spaced grid, and now you want to interpolate again to try and undo the "damage" of that conversion? Sounds like data destruction to me, which might not be needed...Can you perhaps post a bit more background on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't think 90x100 is too large...SO's magic will reduce the size of your block to something reasonable anyway :) Just use `format short` (if you're using `double`) and copy-paste it here

Comment: @Rody: Regarding the copy-paste: Data don't fit. The post is limited to 30k chars, mine would be >60k. 
I will edit my processing steps in the above post!

Answer (score 2):

You might try the `TriScatteredInterp` function. It works well in my simple test:

```
% create an image with holes
x = im2double(imread('rice.png'));
x(1:4:end, 1:4:end) = nan;
x(rand(size(x))<.1) = nan;
figure; imshow(x);

% setup the grid to interp from
[m n c] = size(x);
[N M] = meshgrid(1:m, 1:n);
Ni = N;
Mi = M;

Mi(~isnan(x)) = [];
Ni(~isnan(x)) = [];

N(isnan(x)) = [];
M(isnan(x)) = [];
Z = x(~isnan(x));

% do the interp
F = TriScatteredInterp(M', N', Z);
Zi = F(Mi, Ni);

xi = x;
xi(sub2ind(size(x),Mi, Ni)) = Zi;
figure; imshow(xi);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation and simple imdilate worked for me. `TriScatteredInterp` is quite slow. The post is quite old but maybe following code helpful to somebody:

```
imgDepth = load('depthImage.mat') % Or imread('depthImage.png')
imgDepth(isnan(imgDepth)) = 0
radius = 10 % Change as per your data
se = strel('disk',radius) % Try different structuring elements as per your need
imgDilated = imdilate(imgDepth,se);
figure,imshow(imgDilated,[]),colormap(jet)
```